# esc_html don't work on variable but do work on pasted text

Tags: escaping

My posts have Custom Fields, one of which includes code snippets. I tried esc_html() to present them on the site. this is what I do:

```
$code = get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'code_snippet')[0];
$code_html = esc_html($code);
echo $code_html;
```

This doesn't work. It prints the code but whenever there are `<`or `>` it interprets it as HTML and collapses everything in between as if it was a tag.

However, if I copy the same text from the Custom Field in the dashboard and paste it into the code (so assign $code the pasted string) it *does* work. And I don't understand why.

Edit: ✅ Solved! It seems like `get_post_meta()` is returning an already "stripped" string. I changed how I get the custom field content to

```
$code = get_post_custom_values($key = 'code_snippet');
echo esc_html($code[0]);
```

and now it is working.

Comment: I am starting to think that `get_post_meta()` is stripping the code so `esc_html` isn't doing anything. The snippet is correct when I look at it in the Dashboard, but not when I retrieve it with `get_post_meta()`. So something is happening there. Could that be the case?